# Arduino IDE ESP32-C3 hidden I2C initialisation / hidden Wire.begin()

Tags: arduino, esp32, i2c, arduino-ide, arduino-esp32

I suspect that the Arduino IDE includes a bunch of code for the ESP32 / ESP32-C3, based on the selected "board" dropdown. I think in this code, I2C is being initialized with the default pins.

I noticed that the ESP32-C3 prints this out on boot:

```
ESP-ROM:esp32c3-api1-20210207
Build:Feb  7 2021
rst:0x1 (POWERON),boot:0xf (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
SPIWP:0xee
mode:DIO, clock div:1
load:0x3fcd5810,len:0x438
load:0x403cc710,len:0x918
load:0x403ce710,len:0x25f4
entry 0x403cc710
[   178][I][esp32-hal-i2c.c:75] i2cInit(): Initialising I2C Master: sda=8 scl=9 freq=100000
```

The last line here is of interest, it seems to be establishing I2C with the pins 8 and 9 for SDA and SCL. At that point in the code, I haven't got to `setup()` yet, and I don't think any library is initializing that early.

The problem: In `setup()`, I tried this:

```
// First,
  Wire.setPins(10, 1); // SDA, SCL
// Then, later (called inside of a library)
  Wire.begin();
```

But this fails to work, unless I actively stop the I2C connection first, like this:

```
 Wire.end();
 Wire.setPins(SDA_PIN, SCL_PIN);
 Wire.begin(); // Called inside of a library
```

Which now works. This isn't the end of the world, but I don't like that there's code running before my code, that I can't see. I suppose this is the trade-off of using Arduino IDE.

My question:
Where is the hidden `Wire.begin()`?
How do I find what code is included in my sketch, based on what board I have selected in the dropdown menu in the Arduino IDE?

Comment: Go look at the main function in main.c for whatever particular core you are using and see what all it does.  You will probably have to chase some calls down and figure out what some defines mean.  grep is your friend.

Comment: Sure, grep is great, but where are the files that the Arduino is including? Again, my question is "how do I find the code"?

Comment: For Arduino framework, when you are calling Wire.begin() without specify the pin, it automatically setup the pin with the default pin defined as `SDA` and `SCL`, Every board might assigned different pin to those macro. For generic ESP32-C3, you can find it the definition [here](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/variants/esp32c3/pins_arduino.h#L24-L25)

Comment: " I don't like that there's code running before my code, that I can't see". Like it or not, there are a lot of code running before you can use your board. How else you think that you can use your Serial, or USB or anything, and where the "setup()" and "loop()" get called? Take a look at the main.c [here](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/cores/esp32/main.cpp) for ESP32, and [here](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/cores/arduino/main.cpp) for an Arudino Uno.